Move suggested actions in the duplicate autocomment to the close banner
As so eloquently put by Shadow Wizard:

There is already the "official" close banner appearing (for the OP only) on top of the question when there are pending close votes/flags - the information that is currently given in the auto comment should be there.
This auto comment is ancient artifact of the past, before there was the aforementioned banner.

The banner has a lot of empty space in it, let us put it to good use. IIRC the final banner after closing already has suggested actions to take, it's not that far of a step from that to the suggestions being present in the same place before the question is closed.
And we shouldn't be overloading a single comment with so much information, when all of it is already presented to the poster elsewhere. The dupe target is already in the banner, and if you disagree with a duplicate suggestion, this pop-up appears:


Thanks! Edit your question to explain how it's different from the suggested questions. This will help prevent your question from getting closed and will remove the suggested questions notification from your post.

Does that seem a bit familiar?

A simple comment with just the mention of the dupe target (like we have had since this system basically began) should be sufficient, and I'd like it to remain, since, unlike any of the other close votes, it provides a useful signal even if the question didn't get closed.

Posting this is a separate FR from https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401019/270345 so that only one suggestion being implemented doesn't result in the other being forever ignored

it's unfortunate that one user posting multiple requests simultaneously can lead to votes being incorrectly reversed

It's unfortunate that separate suggestions for the same system have to be posted separately to avoid feature requests being closed as a duplicate of something that partially overlaps, or incorrectly marked [tag:status-completed] when only partially implemented.

I mean, they don't have to be, but that wasn't a comment on you doing something incorrectly, just a shortcoming of the serial voting reversal script. Ideally stack's CM's would create separate tickets internally to track each of the requests, regardless of whether they share a single question on meta (which i'm pretty sure they do?)

It is an integral part of SE's Q&A format that the OP is not the only person with an interest in the question. Rather, a question exists for anyone with a similar problem, and everyone is free to help curate posts by editing. Notably, many people are not familiar with curation on SE and frequently need a reminder.
So showing advice only to the OP when it is relevant for anyone isn't ideal.
While I would not bet on the "you" in the comment being meant generic, it certainly does not hurt to be written as such. Instead of throwing out the advice with the bathwater, it might be better to fix the implied focus on the OP.

This question is similar to: (link to the duplicate). If you believe it is different, please [edit] the question to make it clear how it is different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your this problem.


Even with the rewording, I don't think anybody will actually think that the "you" in the instruction is directed to anybody other than the OP. Especially not people unfamiliar with curation on SE.

@muru I've aimed for a minimal edit for demonstration, of course a more extensive change or starting from scratch with intention would make the message better. The point remains, though, that the information should be directed at a broader audience instead of a smaller one.
